# save JSON in chunks with PyMongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a decent sized collection in MongoDB and I need to export the entire thing to JSON using PyMongo. Right now I'm just doing:

```
import json

results = db.collection_name.find()

with open('collection-data.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(list(results), f)
```

This ends up crashing the kernel because it eats up all my memory. Is there a way to save the collection in chunks so that I don't retrieve all of the data at one time?

Comment: Rather than use `list()`, iterate the cursor in chunks of, say, 10000, and write each chunk to the file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your shell:

```
mongoexport --db <database-name> --collection <collection-name> --out output.json
```